# immediately start MediaPlayer and update MediaPlayerControl

Tags: android

I want to immediately start playing a sound when the activity is first launched and I want the `MediaPlayerControl` object to reflect this change. On the code given below the controls will start with play-mode activated instead of pause-mode (since the file is already playing).

```
public class Guide extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayerControl, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private MediaPlayer m_audio_player;
    private MediaController m_audio_controller;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guide);
        set_up_audio();
    }

    private void set_up_audio(){
        m_audio_player = MediaPlayer.create(this, *SOMESOUNDFILE*);
        m_audio_player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        m_audio_controller = new MediaController(this);
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        m_audio_controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        m_audio_controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.main_audio_view));
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                m_audio_controller.setEnabled(true);
                m_audio_controller.show();
                m_audio_player.start();
                // how do I update m_audio_controller's state here?
            }
        });
    }
}
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. If I call `show` after first having started the player, it does work.

```
m_audio_player.start();
m_audio_controller.show();
```